# Find $\frac{FE}{FD}$ in a triangle where you know $AB$, $AE$, $EC$

Tags: geometry, triangles

In the triangle $ABC$, $AB=39$, $AE=9$, $EC=16$ ($E$ is a point on $AC$). Find the ratio $\frac{FE}{FD}$.
[image: triangle]

So far, using the right triangle altitude theorem and Pitagora's theorem, I have found:

$DE=12\\AD=15\\DC=20\\BD=36$

But I don't know how to continue it. Can you help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us make a slightly more accurate picture...

[image]

I've also constructed the projection $X$ of $B$ on the line $AC$.

Then
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{16}{EX}
&=
\frac{CE}{EX}
=
\frac{CD}{DB}
=
\frac{20}{36}
\ ,
\\[4mm]
\frac{12}{BX}
&=
\frac{DE}{BX}
=
\frac{CD}{CB}
=
\frac{20}{56}
\ ,
\\[4mm]
&\qquad\text{ and from here}
\\[4mm]
EX&=
\frac{144}5=28.8\ ,\\
BX&=
\frac{168}5=33.6\ ,
\\[4mm]
\frac{FE}{FA}
&=
\cot \widehat {AEF} = \cot \widehat {XEB}
\\
&=
\frac{XE}{XB}=
\frac{144}{168}=
\frac 67\ ,
\\[4mm]
\frac{FA}{FD}
&=
\frac
{\sin \angle ADF}
{\sin \angle DAF}
=
\frac
{\sin \angle ABF}
{\sin \angle DBF}
=
\frac
{\sin \angle ABE}
{\sin \angle EBC}
\\
&
=
\frac
{2\text{Area}(ABE)/(BA\cdot BE)}
{2\text{Area}(EBC)/(BC\cdot BE)}
=
\frac
{\text{Area}(ABE)/BA}
{\text{Area}(EBC)/BC}
=
\frac
{AE/BA}
{EC/BC}
\\
&=\frac{9/39}{16/56}=\frac{21}{26}\ ,
\\[4mm]
\frac{FE}{FD}
&=
\frac{FE}{FA}
\cdot
\frac{FA}{FD}
\\
&=\frac 67\cdot \frac{21}{26}=\frac 9{13}\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
(I have to submit, check the computation later, but the computational bridge should work.)

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

This problem is screaming for coordinate system (say with $BC$ as x-axis and $AD$ as y-axis.)

Comment: Nice suggestion, but I have only managed to write the ratio in term of one coordinate of $F$...